# Crash on unsigned char of an image due to bad access

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, char, rgb

Im trying to get RGB values of an image at particular point. Sometimes it get crashed by bad access.

```
+ (void)pixelValueForData:(unsigned char*)data
               atOffset:(int)offset {
        int red = data[offset+1];
        int green = data[offset+2];
        int blue = data[offset+3];
        NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i ",offset,red,green,blue);
}
```

offset calculated as

```
                int offset = 4*((width*y)+x);
```

What should i do to avoid that crash ?

Comment: Most likely you're calculating the offset incorrectly, though it's hard to tell because you haven't provided any useful information on the problem. What offsets are you passing in? How is your image created? Why are you passing in an offset instead of an x and y coordinate? (Or is your image one dimensional?)

Comment: Are you sure you're using 'C++', and not some other language?  That's the oddest 'C++' function definition I've ever seen.

Comment: Its objective c. Most time it works fine. But while trying dark images   it get crashed.

Comment: Should i check any limit constrains for offset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was problem with calculating offset. It should obey conditions x >= 0, x <= width , y >=0 and y <= height. offset satisfying above conditions only should pass to  pixelValueForData: method. Else it get crashed.